# Explain please this define

Tags: microcontroller, c

```
#define POKE(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) = (val))
#define POKE_AND(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) &= (val))
#define POKE_OR(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) |= (val))
```

I dont understand what does it mean

```
POKE(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) = (val))
POKE_AND(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) &= (val))
POKE_OR(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) |= (val))
```

for example when i call function

```
ulVal  = PEEK(NETX_IO_CFG);
```

where NETX_IO_CFG

```
#define NETX_IO_CFG     0x00100004U
```

Comment: Which package is this in? I want to buy the writer a beer for using the terms peek and poke!

Comment: in netx500 micricontroller project

Comment: Peek and poke were used in Basic for the Commodore Pet (6502 processor) for accessing individual memory RAM locations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

define has two practices it can be used to define a constant:

```
#define PI (3.14)
```

or it can be used to define macros(somehow look like functions) and it's inlined directly into the code, so there isn't any function call overhead as in :

```
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

in this case,

```
#define POKE(addr, val) (*(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) = (val))
```

is a macro(like a function) to store `val` into the address `addr` by using the concept of pointers

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)

Comment: Also see [PEEK and POKE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PEEK_and_POKE) for some historical reference regarding those terms.

Answer (score 2):

here is being used the way to declare a **macro** in C compilers. the compiler changes the expression **POKE(addr, val)** by ***(volatile unsigned int *)(addr) = (val)** in code which means to assign variable **val** to derreferenced and ***casted***((volatile unsigned int *)) pointer  **addr**, so on for the remains. Sorry, English is not my first idiom.